# Uso de JSON en PHP

Tags: java, php, json

Estoy utilizando [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) desde Java para recibir y solicitar datos en formato JSON desde PHP. Pero no doy con la manera de hacer el código correcto desde PHP para enviar y recibir y en Java para recibir.

*Código JAVA para enviar y recibir*

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONManager<T> {

    // CLASS PROPERTIES

    private static JSONManager ourInstance = new JSONManager();

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static final String SERVER_PATH = "http://localhost/";

    // CLASS METHODS

    public static JSONManager getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    // CONSTRUCTORS

    private JSONManager() {
    }

    // METHODS

    public synchronized void send() throws IOException{

        // SE AÑADEN ALGUNOS DATOS...

        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.put("name","foo");
        jsonObject.put("age", 20);

        final List listOfJSONObjects = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonObject));

        // SE GENERA EL STRING DE JSON...

        String jsonString = JSONValue.toJSONString(listOfJSONObjects);

        // SE MUESTRA POR CONSOLA EL JSON GENERADO...

        System.out.printf("JSON generado: %s \n\n", jsonString);

        // SE CODIFICA EL JSON A UNA URL

        jsonString = URLEncoder.encode(jsonString, "UTF-8");
        String urlString = SERVER_PATH+"onListenerJSONJava.php"; // TODO <-- No se cómo debe ser el código allí.

        // SE GENERA UNA URL Y SE ABRE LA CONEXIÓN CON EL SERVIDOR

        final HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();

        // SE AÑADE LA CABECERA

        huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        huc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        huc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        // SE ENVIAN LOS DATOS

        final String postParameters = "jsonJAVA="+jsonString;

        huc.setDoOutput(true);
        final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(huc.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(postParameters);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        // SE CAPTURA LA RESPUESTA DEL SERVIDOR

        final int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode(); // TODO <-- No se cómo debe ser el código allí.

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        // SE MUESTRA POR CONSOLA EL 'MENSAJE' ENVÍADO AL SERVIDOR Y SU CÓDIGO DE RESPUESTA

        System.out.printf("\nSending 'POST' request to URL: %s\nPost parameters: %s\nResponse code: %d\n",
                urlString, postParameters,responseCode);

        // SE MUESTRA LA RESPUESTA DEL SERVIDOR Y SE CIERRA LA CONEXIÓN

        System.out.printf("\nResponse: %s:",response.toString());
        br.close();
    }

    public <T extends Object> T receive() {
        // TODO <-- No sé hacerlo aquí.
        return null;
    }

}
```

*Código PHP para recibir. // Fala enviar...*

```
    if(isset($_POST["jsonJAVA"])){

        $json = $_POST["jsonJAVA"];

        // EN ESTE PUNTO NO SÉ COMO OBTENER EL JSON DESDE MI APP EN JAVA Y RESPONDER POR SUPUESTO...

            // TODO

        // GUARDAR DATOS EN BBDD SI ES NECESARIO TRAS VALIDARLOS...

            // TODO <-- Esto ya sé hacerlo.
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hola dddenis, la pregunta no esta muy clara. Puedes explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer, lo que haz intentado y cual es el problema que estas teniendo?

Comment: La pregunta ha mejorado con la última edición

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la parte de Java te puedo ayudar.

Para enviar datos hacia el servidor, obviamente vamos a utilizar el método POST, ahora; lo que no me gusta del enfoque que estás llevando es la manera en la que creas el JSON. Java es un lenguaje orientado a objetos y por ende los problemas deben ser tratados de esa manera, te propongo lo siguiente:

Supongamos que quiero enviar un JSON de tipo Persona, una persona tiene atributos nombre y apellido; entonces creo un objeto Persona así:

```
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    //incluir los metodos get y set para cada atributo
}
```

Luego en alguna parte de mi código, debo poblar la trama que quiero enviar al servidor, ya sea por base de datos o con datos estáticos

```
 Persona p = new Persona();
 p.setNombre("Yo");
 p.setApellido("Tu");
```

Para convertir esta clase en un JSON al vuelo te recomiendo [esto](https://github.com/ropherpanama/JSONParser/blob/master/src/com/cursoup/parser/Parser.java) que hice usando Gson

```
private static Gson gson = new Gson();

public static String objetoAJson(Object o) {
    return gson.toJson(o);
}
```

De esa manera solo pasas el objeto (Lista o Objeto unico) al método `objetoAJson` y se retornará un `String` con tu JSON listo para enviar.

Ahora, luego de que tienes el JSON listo, debes enviarlo con un POST

Te propongo este método

```
public static String sendPost(String url, String data) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection  con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(data);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        data = null;

        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);

        InputStream it = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputs = new InputStreamReader(it);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputs);
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        System.out.println("Servidor dice : " + response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }
```

Sólo debes definir la URL a donde debe llegar el contenido, y por supuesto; el contenido (JSON ) que vas a enviar. El resto depende del tu código en el servidor que está en PHP y ahí si que no sé porque evito PHP.

Para recibir JSON desde tu servidor, usamos GET (más sencillo aún)

```
public static InputStream getJson(String _url) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(_url);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            return urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
}
```

El resultado se retornará en un InputStream que puede ser transformado a String así:

```
String text = new Scanner(>>aquí tu stream recibido<<).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Y listo, tendrás la respuesta del servidor (JSON o algún error) y podrás trabajar con ello.

Cualquier duda, a la orden.
Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde entiendo, estás realizando una petición `XHR` desde Java a `PHP`, en la cual el contenido de la petición es un `JSON`. De ser así, en tu archivo `PHP` la forma de interpretar sería utilizando [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["jsonJAVA"])){
        $json = json_decode($_POST["jsonJAVA"]);

        # De aquí en adelante es validar, guardar en DB 
        # y responder

    }
```

Comment: nota: si el php está en otra ip/servidor hay que decirle que acepte la petición poniendo al principio `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Answer (score 0):

El PHP debe devolver algun tipo de dato HTML.
PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor y la peticion JAVA se hace del lado del cliente, por lo que tienes que escribir algun dato tipo HTML, como si estuvieras visitando una página web.
Me explico con tu ejemplo:

```
<?php
    // Comprobacion
    if(isset($_POST["jsonJAVA"])){
        // Ejecutas todo el contenido que quieras hacer con esta
        // variable, ya sea guardar o sacar datos.
        // Si quisieras sacar valores a datos json seria:
        $json['nombre_salida'][] = array('variable' => 'dato', 'variable' => 'dato'); //Etc
    }
    // Finalmente necesitamos establecer las cabeceras y sacar los datos a HTML
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Esa seria la sintaxis.
Saludos.